# Принципиальное отличие способов приведения к массиву

Tags: массивы

Всем доброго дня. Подскажите пожалуйста, чем отличаются эти две записи?

```
const a = (...args) => Array.of(...args);
const b = Array.of;
```

Comment: Второй теряет this=Array, но я не в курсе, нужен ли он ему)

Comment: Добавьте метку языка программирования в вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Второй способ теряет контекст, что для данной конкретной функции не принципиально, поскольку она его не использует.

Правильнее было бы записать `const b = Array.of.bind(Array)`

В отличии от этого способа, первый создаёт лишний уровень в стеке вызовов.

Если некто додумается испортить метод: `Array.of = () => [];`, первый способ изменит поведение, а второй нет)

В остальном, функционально способы идентичны.